# List animations ignoring Animation parameter

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-animation

I've been trying to get changes to my list elements to animate correctly. However, items in a list don't seem to animate as specified.

In this simple example, an element is removed. There is an animation, within 1 second the element is removed. However, it completely ignores the duration and delay.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("Item \(item)")
                }
            }
            
            Button {
                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 5).delay(1)) {
                    
                    print("removing element")
                    items.removeFirst()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Remove element")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the List and just have a VStack of items, the Animation parameter is processed correctly.

If I remove the withAnimation, it doesn't animate at all. So it is triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is expected as this is how underlying `UITableViewController` is working, it doesn't have capabilities to customise animations that way.

I think that if you want to do something custom you need to start with `LazyVStack` in `ScrollView`, that will give you more space for creation and it is quite likely that this would work (I haven't tried it, but from the logical point it should).